# Razor and displaying a properties value?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'll keep it simple, I have this application that sends back a status "code" to a page, as of right now, I have just the status code displaying on the page. What I want to do and what I have in place is for the system to read the status code, then pull an actual "value" from a database. As it sits, this code displays the status message on the page:

```
<input type="textarea" data-bind="value: property('Message')" readonly />
```

This is all fine and dandy, but there is a text box that I do NOT want to display, and it's only a single line, which means anything past the end would trail off into nothingness. How can I take this line of code, and make it so the value of the status message(HTML from a database) will be displayed?

Perhaps something with an `@Html.Raw()` so the HTML coming from the DB will be rendered?

Answer (score 0):

usually what i do is i convert the model values to json object and populate the required client side from that object ie

```
<script>
var jsonData= @Html.Raw(json.Encode(model));
$(function(){
RenderView();

})

function RenderView(){
$(jsonData).each(function(){    //if list
 $('inputID').val(this.modelPropertyname)
})

}

</script>
```